# How can the root directory in python chunk be specified?

Tags: python, r, path, knitr, blogdown

Setting the root directory in a python-chunk with the following code line results in an error while for an ordinary r-chunk it works just fine

```
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir ="..")
```

```
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir ="..")
```

Optimally there should exist the following options for each knitr-chunk:
- directory to find code to be imported / executed
- directory to find files / dependencies that are needed for code execution
- directory to save any code output

Does something similar exist?

Comment: this question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512545/root-directory-for-python-chunk-in-knitr but I cannot make it work

Answer (score 1):

What it looks like here is that you have told it that it is to look for python code:

````
```{python}
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir ="..")
```
````

When you run this in R studio it will give you an error:

Error: invalid syntax (, line 1)

You fed it python code instead.  This makes sense as the call knit::opt_knit$set means to look in the knitr package for the opts_knit$set and set it to…. This doesn’t exist in python… yet.  The python compiler does not recognize it as python code and returns a syntax error.  Whereas when you run it as an R chunk, it knows to look into the knitr package.  Error handling can be huge issue to deal with. It makes more sense to handle error categories than to account for every type of error.  If you want to control the settings for a code chunk, you would do so in the parenthesis ie:

````
```{python, args }
codeHere
```
````

I have not seen args for any other language than R, but that does not mean it doesn’t exist.  I have just not seen them.  I also do not believe that this will fix your issue. You could try some of the following ideas:

- Writing your python in a separate file and link to it.  This would allow for you to take advantage of the language and utilize things like the OS import.  This may be something you want to consider as even python has its ways of navigating around the various operating systems.  This may be helpful if you are just running quick scripts and not loading or running python programs.

  ```
  # OS module
  import os
  # Your os name 
  print(os.name)
  # Gets PWD or present working directory
  os.getcwd()
  # change your directory
  os.chdir("path")
  ```
- You could try using the reticulate library within an R chunk and load your python that way
- Another thought is that you could try

  library(reticulate)
  use_python(“path”)
- Knitr looks in the same directory as your markdown file to find other files if needed.  This is just like about any other IDE
- At one point in time knitr would not accept R’s setwd() command. Trying to call setwd() may not do you any good.
- It may not the best idea to compute paths relative to what's being executed. If possible they should be determined relative to where the user calls the code from.

[This site may help](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/language-engines.html).

The author of the knitr package is very active and involved. Good luck with what you are doing!

Comment: I have not found "args" that could set the directory where the python-file is stored, neither where a possible  output-file (e.g. plot) should be stored. (Reopening my pyton-files and setting output directories is time consuming.) This would allow cleaner integration of python-code output (in e.g. blogdown). Reticulate is nice if I want to use python-code variables in R-code but it does not work well with all python packages.